# Keyboard Extension not working properly after iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, custom-keyboard

I made a [custom Keyboard app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/famoji-keyboard-send-funny/id1135918314?mt=8) with emojis some time ago for iOS 9.

After iOS 10 came out it stopped working, now only loads the bottom view.
[image]

I can't quite figure out what's wrong  with my code or what change with iOS 10, I spent the last couple of days searching the web but couldn't find anything useful

Here's the code where it should load the emojis

```
 - (void)loadNthEmoji{
    [self.keyboard.imvFavorite setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_favorite"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSInteger nTag = [defaults integerForKey:@"EMOJI_FACE_EMOJI_KIND"];
    if (nTag == 0)nTag = 1;

    [self setAlpha:nTag];
    [self removeSubViewFromEmojiView];


    CGRect rectWrapper = self.keyboard.scvEmojis.frame;

    CGFloat fSpace = 4;
    NSInteger nEmojiRow = 3;
    CGFloat fHeight = ((rectWrapper.size.height - (nEmojiRow + 1) * fSpace) / nEmojiRow);
    CGFloat fWidth = fHeight;

    NSInteger nCount = [[arrCounts objectAtIndex:nTag]integerValue];

    for (NSInteger i = 0 ; i < nCount; i ++){

        NSInteger nRow = i % nEmojiRow;
        NSInteger nColumn = i / nEmojiRow;


        CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(fSpace + (fSpace + fWidth) * nColumn, fSpace + (fSpace + fHeight) * nRow, fWidth/1.3, fHeight/1.3);


        UIImageView *imvEmoji = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectFrame];
        imvEmoji.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imvEmoji.tag = 10000 * nTag + i;
        [imvEmoji setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ec%i (%i).png", (int)nTag, (int)i + 1]]];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tabEmoji:)];

        [imvEmoji setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imvEmoji addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        [self.keyboard.scvEmojis addSubview:imvEmoji];

    }

    [self.keyboard.scvEmojis setContentSize:CGSizeMake(fSpace + (fSpace + fWidth) * ((int)(nCount / nEmojiRow) + (nCount % nEmojiRow == 0 ? 0 : 1)), rectWrapper.size.height)];

    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [self.keyboard.viewEmoji setHidden:NO];

}
```

Edit: still no luck, any help?

Comment: Are you testing on simulator? If Yes then check for Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard.

Comment: Tested in both simulator and iPhone. The keyboard comes up but it's not showing the full view, just that bottom bar

Comment: Did you figure this out? I believe I am experiencing the same issue, outlined in a sample project here: https://github.com/DimaVartanian/keyboard-extension-height-bug

Comment: @Dima No I didn't but yes it looks like the same issue. I will share if I get it solved

Comment: @emiliomarin I'm also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it solved by setting a new constrain for the height. In case it helps anyone with the same problem. I tried a lot of answer I found but any worked for me.

[image]

Comment: So you just set an explicit constant for the height? What about different screen sizes and different orientations? What does it look like on something like an iPad Pro?

Comment: @Dima In my case it has only one size, not using iPad  and only portrait. But I'm sure your problem has to be with the constrains you have, play around with them

Comment: @emiliomarin it is working but I think it is not the correct solution. If my keyboard is set for both landscape and portrait modes what should I have to do??